# Why is Edge fetching every module/component as http request?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microsoft-edge, node-modules

We have a SPA built with React and bundled with Webpack.
The server only has the index.html and javascript bundle files located.

#### Behaviour Chrome/Firefox/Opera

1. Loads index.html
2. Fetches bundles
3. Boots React page
   [image: Chrome DevTools Screenshot]

#### Behaviour Edge

1. Loads index.html
2. Fetches bundles
3. Boots React page
4. Starts loading every module and component as an independent file using HTTP requests (they are not even on the server, the response is index.html)
   [image: Edge DevTools Screenshot]

The bundle does not have this information. This information must be fetched from the source map. But why does Edge do this?

Comment: I try to find the documentation but I did not got any information why MS Edge is downloading the files like this. It can be by design. I will try to discuss the issue with some senior engineers and let you know about their suggestions. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar like SAP application, those JavaScript library has their own logic to preload source codes to optimize the performance/network requests. It's a compatibility issue with React library for Edge browser.

The next version of Edge browser don't have this issue. Maybe you want to try this: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/